# Permissions in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I need the command to work if the user has either admin rights or the rights to ban members.  [In my dreams it looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEh8p.png)

```
I looked for a solution in the documentation, unfortunately I did not find anything suitable
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True)
```

Try and see if this works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).